# jQuery filter table - exclude instead of include

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, html-table

I am currently using this code (from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_filters.asp)) to add a filter search to an HTML table:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

My question is, is it possible to have this code exclude the matched result(s) instead of include? I've tried manipulating the code in all sorts of ways but to no avail. Admittedly, I am very new to JS/jQuery coding.

Comment: you can try changing `$(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)` to `$(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) === -1)`

Comment: @Karma Blackshaw that sort of works, but when you erase the search text, the starting rows no longer appear (the table is empty).

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov Yes, I responded now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test if the input is not an empty string, store the value in a variable and use that to filter the items:

```
var show = (value !== '') ? ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) === -1) : true;
$(this).toggle(show);
```

As Karma said, this will exclude the items which contain the input string, but will not hide all items when the input is empty.

Hope you've found this helpful.

Comment: Your response is the only one that works with all browsers, and returns the proper results when the search field is empty (after typing something in and deleting it)! Thanks a lot, great work!

Answer (score 0):

You can opposite indexOf() result to your current one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) === -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: There is no way `indexOf` will return a value lower than -1.